# Enable/disable row based on the value from MultipleSelectorRow

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eureka-forms

This is a question related to the Swift open source project called [Eureka](http://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and I'm posting this question here on SO since they monitor their tag here.

I have created a form which has a `MultipleSelectorRow` and following that, a `TextRow`. That `TextRow` is disabled by default. The `MultipleSelectorRow` shows a list of options.

```
form
    +++ Section()
    <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>("Lead") {
        $0.title = "Lead"
        $0.options = ["Yahoo", "Yelp", "Google", "Referral or Other"]
    }
    .onPresent { from, to in
        to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: from, action: #selector(ViewController.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
    }
    <<< TextRow("Referral") {
        $0.title = "Note Referral or Other"
        $0.disabled = "$Lead != 'Referral or Other'"
    }
```

What I want is if the user selects the last option, *Referral or Other*, I want the `TextRow` to be enabled.

My current implementation above doesn't do this. It stays disabled. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition `MultipleSelectorRow<T>` holds a `Set<T>` as a value type and seems you are wrongly expecting a String value.

Having said that you should try on with this predicate...

```
$0.disabled = "NOT $Lead contains 'Referral or Other'"
```

or alternatively..

```
$0.hidden = Condition.Function(["Lead"]) { form in
        if let r1 : MultipleSelectorRow <String> = form?.rowByTag("tag1") {
            return r1.value.contains("Referral or Other") == false
        }
        return false
}
```